# Embeddings and Imbeddings

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am studying Sobolev Spaces and I am very confused about the following:

**What are the difference between the Embeddings and Imbeddings of spaces?**

**If I have that: $W^{k,p}\to W^{m,q} $  is a compact imbedding, so it means that $W^{k,p}\subset W^{m,q} $ or not ?**

Comment: Apparenlty "embed" and "imbed" are alternative spellings of the same verb. Personally, I prefer embed.

Comment: I once saw a subtle difference in the wording in literature. In the book of Girault&Raviart they do not include injectivity in "embedding" (but in imbedding). This is useful for Navier-Stokes function spaces, since the divergence-free space $H^1_{div}$ is not dense in $H_0^1$, and therefore, the dual $H^{-1}$ is not injective in $(H^1_{div})'$. Nonetheless, they use the word "embedding" for the continuous restriction operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Gae. S. in comments is correct: embeddings and imbeddings are alternate spellings of each other.

A compact im/embedding $\iota : X\to Y$ between Banach spaces, say (which already means $\iota (X) \subset Y$) is a map satisfying the following:

- (embedding property) $\iota$ is injective,
- (Continuity) we have the norm bound $ \|\iota(u)\|_Y \le C \|u\|_X$ for some $C>0$,
- (Compactness) if $u_n$ is a bounded sequence of $X$, then $\iota(u_n)$ has a convergent subsequence in $Y$.

So what you said is true: $\iota(W^{k,p})\subset W^{m,q}$, but you have even a quantitative control on norms and the ability to extract convergent subsequences in the 'larger' space. Note that it is common practice to not give a symbol to the embedding map, and say that $X$ **is** a subset of $Y$ (this is the *identification of $X$ with its embedding in $Y$*).